# Creating a Thrift server on stdin with C++

Tags: c++, thrift

I wonder if it's possible to create a Thrift server that would listen on stdin and write the answers to stdout. I found the TFDTransport in Thrift.

```
int fd = fgetc( stdin );
shared_ptr<TFDTransport> innerTransport(new TFDTransport(fd));
shared_ptr<TBufferedTransport> transport(new TBufferedTransport(innerTransport));
```

What I am not sure is how to create a Thrift server that would listen on stdin and write answers to stdout. Here is the standard way of initializing a new server:

```
shared_ptr<TJSONProtocol> protocol(new TJSONProtocol(transport));
TSimpleServer server(processor,
                   serverTransport,
                   transportFactory,
                   protocolFactory);
```

But at this point I am not sure how to progress. Is creating a server on stdin/stdout even possible with Thrift and if so how to create such a server?

Answer (score 1):

Well you would probably need to create your own STDIN/OUT Client and Server Transports. 
It would be easy if the server was the parent process and the client was the child process, but the reverse is much more interesting. It would essentially allow a multi-lang plugin framework of sorts.

I am actually very interested in this as well for same-machine IPC.

Answer (score 1):

If you environment is Windows: There is an implementations for Anon Pipes available in C++, which does exactly that. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1558

Comment: That's interesting, do you know the URL where it's possible to see this?